# How to push notification by time list using work manager in Android

Tags: android, service, push-notification, android-workmanager

I'm a newbie and I need to use **Work Manager** to schedule push notifications.
I searched the document and found the solution but I can't find the answer to schedule the time list using the Work Manager
My question:

I have a time list like: `[08:00,10:11,11:20,11:21]` 
**During that time, my app will push notifications.**
How can I do that?

Please help me!
Thank you, everyone!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.